# Since I get penalized for answering my own questions

Tags: discussion, voting-fraud, sock-puppets

Since most users here don't actually answer most of my questions, I do actually try really hard to solve my own questions. That is the way I work, and so far it has gotten me far. You only learn to improve.

But my biggest issue is I really need to be able to comment on other peoples' posts so I won't have to work my ass off and re-figure out how they did what or what they meant in their posts.

To get to 50 points is going to be an issue for me. Because in reality I'm really answering my own questions. Would it be a big issue if I created another account to answer my own questions and get to the 50 points faster so I could in reality take advantage of this site more and be better at what I do?

Because it's not fair that since I answer my own questions that I don't get any points for them. I'm not gaming the system; I actually put a shitload of work into answering my questions.

The questions are:

1. If I create a new account to answer my questions, will both of my accounts be banned?
2. Or can an administrator help me get to those 50 points faster so I don't have to go to such drastic measures?

Please let me know how to proceed.

Comment: "_Would it be a big issue if i created another account to answer my own questions and get to the 50 points faster so i could in reality take advantage of this site more and be better at what i do?_" Absolutely an issue. That is vote manipulation. 50 rep is not difficult to achieve. Edit 25 questions, ask a couple good questions, or answer a few.

Comment: Your answer to your own question was bad?

Comment: [You can already answer your own questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and get reputation from upvotes on either the question or the answer.

Comment: Have you considered answering someone else's question? If you're great at answering your own questions, you should be good at answering others as well.

Comment: Best luck, you seem on your way getting pruned from the site.

Comment: How do you get penalized? ONE of your answers has a downvote, and it's not a self-answer.... At best you can argue you're not getting the "accepted". But that's by design. If your answer is really good, you'll eventually get upvotes

Comment: Using comments to ask for clarification is mostly meant for questions, less so for answers. It's perfectly fine to ask for approach/code clarifications - for instance on shallow "try this" answers. - But with comments there's always a thin line. Don't try to use them for broadening Q&As. Comments asking about similar code+topics, or subtly changing the scope isn't what they're for, and will usually just go ignored. (TL;DR: The commenting privilige might not be as useful as you imagine.)

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ good thing i asked this then.

Comment: Thank you to all who participated. I love the -20 points.. really made my day.

Comment: @Admin, I got banned from asking questions for asking this question. Can you please lift that because i am a serious user of this website. Im not some 12 year old.

I just spent a crappy day trying to solve something and have something to ask and i cant ask it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Would it be a big issue if I created another account to answer my own questions and get to the 50 points faster so I could in reality take advantage of this site more and be better at what I do?

> 1. If I create a new account to answer my questions, will both of my accounts be banned?

Yes, because

> Because it's not fair that since I answer my own questions that I don't get any points for them.

You *can* get points for answering your own questions — through upvotes on both your question and your answer. So there really isn't any issue with self-answering at all as you seem to think.

Since self-answered questions are not exempt from regular voting, that makes creating alternate accounts an issue, because you'd then be able to exploit this to vote on your own answers using the alts *in addition to* votes from the community.

> 2. Or can an administrator help me get to those 50 points faster so I don't have to go to such drastic measures?

No, see above.

Comment: lol, while they are at it, can an admin help me get to 20k points faster?

Comment: Thanks for answering it honestly. I would hate to get pruned as "πάντα ῥεῖ " put it in context.

Comment: i love how i got negative 20 for asking such a simple question. You gave me a honest answer. Thats all i wanted. People assume that a moran is asking these questions. Good thing i didnt follow my better judgement.

Comment: I have found, and been expressly told, that answering your own question is a recipe for a downvote.  While the site may allow you to answer your own question, you may attract the wrong attention.